# Is PageContext thread shared

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, servlets

In this [link](http://cs.gmu.edu/~offutt/classes/432/examples/jsp/counterScope_jsp.java), I see the following code.

```
synchronized (_jspx_page_context) {
    pageCounter = (jspexamples.counterBean) _jspx_page_context.getAttribute("pageCounter", PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE);
    if (pageCounter == null){
      pageCounter = new jspexamples.counterBean();
      _jspx_page_context.setAttribute("pageCounter", pageCounter, PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE);
    }
}
```

where _jspx_page_context is of type PageContext. Why is there a synchronization on _jspx_page_context? Is PageContext threadshared?

Comment: Could you post the actual JSP that generated that code. PageContext objects are not shared between threads, so the code snippet doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: It is available [here](http://cs.gmu.edu/~offutt/classes/432/examples/jsp/counterScope.txt). I have found similar examples in the tomcat repo as well.

Answer (score 2):

It is **thread-shared**, means more than one thread may access `pagecontext` at any time. So, to make sure **thread safety**, we have to `synchronize` operations on pageContext. Otherwise, multiple threads may update same value and results will be weired.

Comment: If you look at this [link](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet.jsp/attr.html), it seems to me that when the scope is PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE or PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE, there is *absolutely* no way two threads can access at the same time. 

I am less clear about the other scopes and how multiple threads can cause problematic behavior.

Comment: What made you think if scope is PAGE/REQUEST, two threads can't access? Assume you have ajax application and each click triggers an ajax call, isn't that ajax call separate thread?

Comment: @thinksteep you are incorrect. PageContext objects are NOT shared between threads. They are either created new for each request or, depending on servlet engine, they can be pooled on a thread-context basis (i.e. not shared between threads).

Comment: @pap: I am happy to remove my answer if it is wrong. Could you provide any official documentation/reference for your version?